# SQL Select Query for Converting rows to Columns

Tags: sql, pivot

I am having two tables, One table will have the Master records and another table will have the details of that master table. I need the output as shown below.

**Table 1:**

**ID          Description**

1            Sample
2            Sample 1

**Table 2:**


ID    Table1Id        Block       Date                  SampleCollected
1             1                C       24/09/2020               5
2             1                D       24/09/2020               4
3             2                C       24/09/2020               7
4             2                D       24/09/2020               6
5             1                C       25/09/2020               2
6             2                D       25/09/2020               8

**I need the output as shown below**

                  24/09/2020        24/09/2020        25/09/2020        25/09/2020        ……..
                            C                       D                       C                       D                    ……..
Sample                 5                      4                      2                     0                    ……..
Sample 1                7                        6                      0                     8                     ……..

Please help me to resolve this query.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PIVOT` to convert rows to columns. [Official docs for MS SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax)

Answer (score 0):

Please find a possible solution to your problem in this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=496f647657769a903a4c984aad209ed0).

Your idea would result in many columns. The solution could be to pivot with your `Sample` column.
The `cte` is saving a view to use the description of samples from `table1`. The `PIVOT`is based on the samples. The `CASE WHEN` is used to bring zero instead of `NULL`.

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT table2.ID, table1.Description, table2.Block, table2.DateBlock, table2.SampleCollected
FROM table2
JOIN table1
ON table2.SampleID = table1.ID)
SELECT Block, DateBlock,
  CASE WHEN [Sample] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE [Sample] END AS Sample, 
  CASE WHEN [Sample1] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE [Sample1] END AS Sample1
FROM (
SELECT *
FROM cte) AS sourcetable
PIVOT  
(  
SUM(SampleCollected)  
FOR Description IN ([Sample], [Sample1])  
) AS PivotTable
ORDER BY DateBlock, Block;
```

Comment: Thank You for you reply. Yes the output should result into many columns . And the Description will go like this "Sample", "Sample1","Sample2" etc...
                  24/09/2020       24/09/2020       25/09/2020       25/09/2020                                   C                     D                     C                     D                  ……..
Sample                5                      4                      2                     0                  ……..
Sample 1             7                      6                      0                     8                   ……..